# AWS RDS "pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am working on setting up a Postgres instance on AWS through RDS. It has been placed into a VPC with a private subnet where the subnet CIDRs are: `["10.0.21.0/24", "10.0.22.0/24", "10.0.23.0/24"]`.

I have a public subnet and have successfully connected to postgres through a bastion node from public to private subnet and run queries through SSH port forwarding.

However, now I am trying to setup a connection from a lambda that lives in the same private subnet of the VPC. The lambda has access according to the security group, but I receive the following error:

> OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  PAM
>   authentication failed for user "service_worker" FATAL:  pg_hba.conf
>   rejects connection for host "10.0.23.73", user "service_worker",
>   database "myDB", SSL off

I have connected successfully with `service_worker` through the bastion, but for some reason I can't do so through lambda. It seems like Postgres is rejecting this particular host. And I can't find any configuration or documentation that specifies how to change what RDS does when managing this information in the `pg_hba.conf` file.

Does anyone have any insight into telling Postgres that a connection from a host in the same subnet is ok? I'm assuming there is some security policy that I'm somehow missing in the mix of all this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that

> Role-based authentication is currently not supported for Amazon RDS
>   for PostgreSQL and Aurora PostgreSQL.
>
> - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

And because Lambdas inherently use role based auth, this fails.

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong place - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-rds-postgresql-now-supports-iam-authentication. Though it doesn't explain the problem. I have the same issue

Comment: PS: it seems like AWS claims it works but in reality it doesn't. Some workaround if you are not using it from Lambda - https://gist.github.com/quiver/509e1a6e6b54a0148527553502e9f55d#file-iam_auth_psql-sh

Comment: I actually ended up contacting AWS support and they effectively told me it's not currently supported. Although that was a few months ago now so things may have changed since then. Thanks for the links!